# Dual-boot computer boots straight to Ubuntu after putting this command in cmd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 19.04

This is a bit long but please bear with me. I have a **Dell Inspiron** laptop with **Windows 10** pre-installed. I recently installed **Ubuntu 19.04** alongside it by creating a partition in the disk(I chose the 'something else' option during the installation). After the installation completed, my computer booted straight into Windows which was a common problem. So I googled for solutions and stumbled upon this post on this site called 'ItsFoss'(link to the post: https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) where they said the fix for the problem is this commmand in command prompt:
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

So I input this command and my computer boots straight to linux, still no GRUB menu!
and now I'm unable to boot into windows at all.I am a **100% sure** I didn't overwrite the Windows partitions while installing Ubuntu as I booted into Windows **thrice** after completing the Ubuntu installation, so no problems there.

My question is how do I bring up the GRUB menu.

**Here's what I've tried:**

**1.** Pressing shift during the boot-up doesn't bring up the GRUB menu

**2.** When i ran the command `grub-install --version` i got `grub-install (GRUB) 2.02+dfsg1-12ubuntu2`
so that means GRUB is installed,so I thought probably GRUB is not recognizing windows boot, so it directly boots into Ubuntu and wont show the GRUB screen, and I proceeded to write this:
`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and got this:
[GRUB settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVuS.png)

Guides tell me i should find `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and add a # to make it a comment,but as you can see in the image, there is no such line present.

**3.** A similar answer on stackexchange(https://superuser.com/questions/1150534/how-to-boot-into-ubuntu-directly) also asks to do the same thing to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Given the fact that all this happened because of some command in cmd, i am not comfortable putting another command in terminal unless I'm sure.

**4.** I have tried changing boot modes and the problem persists in both BIOS and UEFI, In the UEFI mode no OS is recognized at all

**5.** The secure boot is off.

**I'm at my wits end here, please help**

Comment: found a guy having the EXACT same problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1361356/windows-no-longer-boots-up-bcdedit-command-likely-at-fault. 

Hope this helps in some way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type the command below:

sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub

Change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE and GRUB_TIMEOUT lines to:

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Save using CTRL+O and exit CTRL+X

Then update grub using the command below:
sudo update-grub

Comment: Okay that worked

I did that and the GRUB menu did appear, but Windows did not show up in the options All i saw was:

https://i.imgur.com/LyH5mqC.jpg

Comment: that's all I got...my advice is, install your OSs in UEFI mode if you intend to multi-boot.

Comment: Luckily I installed them in UEFI mode and this answer works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found the solution.
Fix it like this:

1. Use Rufus to write the Ubuntu ISO file to a USB thumb drive to make a bootable, live Ubuntu system.
2. Use the thumb drive and boot your system to the live Ubuntu system you just made.
3. In a terminal run

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update

then

> sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

4. This will install Boot-Repair, which you will use to re-write the GRUB boot loader to your drive.
5. It’s a GUI, not a command line tool so run it and click on the “Recomended Repair” button.
6. The GRUB install should detect the Windows installation and restore the dual boot menu to working order.
7. That should do it.

Comment: Please don’t just post a link - if that link breaks your answer becomes useless. Please post the steps to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: @will why didn't you attempt to answer the question?

Comment: thank you; I think you’ve  missed my point - you’ve answered the question fine, it’s just that link-only answers become pointless if the site they reference goes down. Thank you for putting the steps in. Hopefully whoever down-voted will reverse that if they see the edits you’ve made.

Comment: Alright, I understand @Will